# How to create a new, empty project in Mavensmate?

Tags: mavensmate

I'm new to Mavensmate. I would like to create a new trigger and associated helper class, starting in my sandbox and then deploying to production.

I can't see a way to create a new, empty project in Mavensmate. If I uncheck all the metadata, it just beeps at me. But I don't want to include any of the existing metadata from my sandbox.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to include any existing code?

Answer (score 0):

Without selecting any metadata it will not let you create project. For namesake select some less used metadata component and proceed.